# Jquery Accessing and looping associative object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm having some problems with accessing JSON encoded PHP associative array. I get the JSON encoded array with `$.get();` and assign it to `data` variable.

```
$.get("includes/ajax/public.php", { do: "get-data", id: value },function(data) {
// NO DATA
if (!data || data == 'false') $('#noData').slideDown('slow');
// THERE IS DATA
else {
if ($('#noData').is(':visible')) $('#noData').hide();
$('#records').html(data.totalRecords);
console.log(data["totalRecords"]);
console.log(data);
}
});
```

This is what I get in console.

```
{"totalRecords":1,"data":[{"id":"1","country_id":"224", "name":"data name","address":"data address"}]}
```

I have to access totalRecords and also loop data array. However I can't access it.

```
console.log(data.totalRecords); //outputs undefined.
```

or

```
console.log(data['totalRecords']); //outputs undefined.
```

I could get rid off totalRecords part if I can count how many arrays there is in `data`. `data.length` doesn't work. It should give me just `1` but it gives me more than 100 which is not correct.

I just have to access totalRecords value (or just count how many arrays there is in it), and loop the data to manipulate DOM.

I would be glad if you could help me out with this small problem.

Comment: Could you post where `data` is defined?

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code where you're loading and accessing this JSON. You seem to be using `data` in more than one way, and it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: Edited my question to make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the totalRecords value like so:

```
data.totalRecords
```

it makes sense that it returns 1, since in the json the value of that field is indeed 1:

```
"totalRecords":1
```

You have to use the data field in order to acess the array of elements:

```
data.data
```

**EDIT:** You have to use $.getJSON() method so jQuery interprets it as a JSON and not just raw data.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: That's the problem. It is not giving value 1, it says `undefined`

Comment: What you get when doing a console.log(data); ? also are you sure the link you're passing its returning the json?

Comment: Check the EDIT in the answer.